# Kubernetes Nginx Ingress and Socket.io Connection Issues

Tags: node.js, reactjs, kubernetes, socket.io, kubernetes-ingress

I'm currently having issues with my react app chatting with a nodejs socket.io app.

However, I have narrowed it down and believe it is an ingress misconfiguration. Port-forwarding the socket.io nodejs pod and connecting with react via 127.0.0.1:3020 works fine.

**Socket.io Deployment File**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: websockettest-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: websockettest
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: websockettest
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: websockettest
          image: websockettest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3020
```

**Socket IO Service Config**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: websockettest-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: websockettest
  ports:
    - port: 3020
      targetPort: 3020
```

**Ingress Configuration**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.org/websocket-services: websockettest-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /websockettest/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: websockettest-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 3020
```

**Nodejs Socket.io**

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.set("transports", ["websocket"]);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('connected socket!');

  socket.on('greet', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('respond', { hello: 'Hello' });
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('Socket disconnected');
  });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3020;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}`);
});
```

**React Socket.io-client**

```
// Various Attempts:
// websockettest
// websockettest-cluster-ip-service
// http://192.168.64.11:3020
// :3020/websockettest
// 127.0.0.1:3020 - port forwarding works

const socket = io('192.168.64.11/websockettest', {
  'reconnection': false, 
  transports: ['websocket']
});
```

Comment: `io('192.168.64.11/websockettest', {` is wrong. it sould be `io(':3020/websockettest/', {` notice port and trailing slash (because of your regex)

Comment: if you want port 80 then you need to change `port: 3020` to `port: 80`, then essentially forget about 3020 clientside as its forwarded to 80

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I updated the port to 80 in the ingress + service, as well as swapped to io(':80/websockettest/'). No luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Socket.io has a specific path it uses for websocket communication. Due to this, the kubernetes ingress needs to be configured to support "/socket.io". Additionally, the node.js middleware also needs to have custom namespace for the socket endpoint.

**ingress-ws-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-ws-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.org/websocket-services: "websockettest-cluster-ip-service"

spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /websockettest/.*
            backend:
              serviceName: websockettest-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 3020
          - path: /socket.io/.*
            backend:
              serviceName: websockettest-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 3020
```

**Nodejs Socket.io**

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

const nsp = io.of("/websockettest");

nsp.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('connected socket!');

  socket.on('greet', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    nsp.emit('respond', { hello: 'Hello' });
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('Socket disconnected');
  });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3020;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}`);
});
```

**React Client**

```
const socket = io('/websockettest', {
  'reconnection': true, 
  transports: ['websocket']
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much....... This solution is perfectly working for me in Nextjs too....

Answer (score 0):

Will this nginx ingress, works in Network loadbalancer to connect with websocket

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).