# Unable to connect via websocket to a backend deployed on GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, websocket, socket.io, nestjs, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm deploying `NestJS` and `NextJS` on `GKE`. Also, I am using `GCE Ingress Controller` to use `managed certificate`.

And I'm trying to make a real-time chat using `Nest Gateway` and `socket.io`.

The backend port number is `8080`, and the websocket port also uses the same `8080`.
And the namespace is 'chat'.

So, The client attempts a websocket connection as shown below.

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:8080/chat')
```

It works fine in local environment.

**The problem is that socket connection does not work on GKE.**

Below is the contents of the ingress manifest file.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name:my-service-ip
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: managed-cert
    networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: http-to-https-config
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dev.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: fontend-svc
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend-svc
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /chat
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend-svc
            port:
              number: 80
```

And below is the contents of the backend manifest file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-api
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend-api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: backend-api-app
        image: gcr.io/<PROJECT_ID>/<DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME>:<DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        envFrom:
          - secretRef:
              name: backend-api-secret
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /api/healthz
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /api/healthz
            port: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend-api
  type: NodePort
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
```

Now the client tries to connect the socket like below.

```
const socket = io('https://dev.domain.com/chat')
```

I am getting the error below in my browser.

`GET https://dev.domain.com/socket.io?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OXClghg 404`

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: You're attempting a websocket connection on **http protocol** and also the configuration seems to be on **http protocol**, but as per the error mentioned by you, you’re calling on **https protocol** instead of **http**. Since https uses 443 port as default on the server. You need to define port 443 in the configuration.

Comment: I tried changing the port number 80 to 443, but it didn't work.

Comment: If you don't specify a default backend, GKE provides a default backend that returns 404. This is created as a **default-http-backend** NodePort service on the cluster in the **kube-system** namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by replacing GCE Ingress Controller with Nginx Ingress Controller.

The links below may help.

[Kubernetes Nginx Ingress and Socket.io Connection Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58697950/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-and-socket-io-connection-issues)